Не работает фильтрация по текущему времени
Необходимо отображать новости, срок публикации которых уже наступил, а остальные скрывать до наступления времени публикации. Для этого в контроллере использую данную фильтрацию:
view.py
from django.utils import timezone

class NewsViewSet(GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    queryset = (
        News.objects.all()
        .filter(publicated_at__lt=timezone.now())
        .order_by("-publicated_at", "-created_at")
    )
    permission_classes = [ModerateAndAdminCreateUpdateDeleteOrAuthReadOnly]
    search_fields = ["created_at", "title"]
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_class = NewsDateFilter

settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = "ru-RU"

TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Moscow"

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

Время привел в соответствие согласно часовым поясам(соответствует при выводе, в БД и в timezone.now()), но все-равно часть записей не выводится после наступления даты публикации. При этом после перезапуска приложения эти записи выводятся в список.
Такое ощущение, что значение timezone.now() не присваивается динамически, а становится фиксированным и равняется времени запуска приложения.

«timezone.now() не присваивается динамически» — ну да, в показанном коде нет никаких причин, почему оно должно присваиваться динамически, queryset вместе с условием создаётся один раз в момент запуска программы и на этом всё

А если хотите динамику, то вместо переменной queryset создайте функцию def get_queryset(self): return ...

@andreymal Благодарю. Перенос фильтрации в get_queryset помог решить проблему.
